# How do I change a fields value with a select?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a select field with different options. If option 'London' is picked I wanna have a disabled input field where the google maps Link of London is written down for example, so the user can copy the link from the disabled input. 
How do I achieve this?

```
<select class="uk-select uk-form-blank uk-form-width-medium uk-margin-small-bottom">
    <option>London</option>
    <option>Paris</option>
    <option>Berlin</option>
</select>

<input value="" class="uk-input uk-form-blank uk-form-width-medium uk-margin-small-bottom" type="text" disabled>
```

Comment: Hello Chase, do you have some example code of what you are attempting using Javascript? It's possible to achieve what you are asking in a multitude of ways. Post your example code and we can guide you to your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `onchange` handler that gets called whenever an option is selected. You can then use `selectedIndex` to find the selected option and update the inputs value with the options text:

```js
const handleChange = e => {
  if(e.selectedIndex > 0) {
    document.querySelector('.uk-input').value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="uk-select uk-form-blank uk-form-width-medium uk-margin-small-bottom" onchange="handleChange(this)">
  <option value="-1">Select Location:</option>
  <option value="http://london.map.google.com">London</option>
  <option value="http://paris.map.google.com">Paris</option>
  <option value="http://berlin.map.google.com">Berlin</option>
</select>

<input value="" class="uk-input uk-form-blank uk-form-width-medium uk-margin-small-bottom" type="text" disabled>
```

**Update**

Added default option and `selectedIndex` validation

**Update 2**

Use option `value` instead of `text` so that you can display a short name and still get the full url to display in the input

Comment: You can put it in a separate file and then import it using: `<script src="./myScript.js"></script>` or use `<script>` blocks directly in the body: `<script type="text/javascript"> // Code here... </script>`

Answer (score 2):

For most cases this simple code would work, but I highly recommend you to look into Google Maps API.

```js
$('.uk-select').change(function(){
 
 $('.uk-input').val("https://www.google.pt/maps/place/"+this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="uk-select uk-form-blank uk-form-width-medium uk-margin-small-bottom">
                
                <option selected disabled>Choose one</option>
                <option>London</option>
                <option>Paris</option>
                <option>Berlin</option>
              </select>

<input style="width:250px" value="" class="uk-input uk-form-blank uk-form-width-medium uk-margin-small-bottom" type="text" disabled>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to select London as the first option.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `$(...).on('change', ...);` to listen for an update in the dropdown. @TiagoVitorino's answer suggests a great way to go about getting the location on Google Maps, but if that's not an option, you can always pull from a data source using the value from the selected option.

```js
// The data that we want to insert into the output
let data = {
  London: "London URL",
  Paris: "Paris URL",
  Berlin: "Berlin URL",
};

// Selecting our elements
let $dropdown = $('.uk-select');
let $output = $('.uk-input');

// Initially populating the output
updateOutput();

// Listen for a change in the dropdown
$dropdown.on('change', updateOutput);

// Update our output based on the dropdown value
function updateOutput() {
  let selected = $dropdown.find('option:selected').val();
  $output.val(data[selected]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="uk-select uk-form-blank uk-form-width-medium uk-margin-small-bottom">
    <option>London</option>
    <option>Paris</option>
    <option>Berlin</option>
</select>

<input value="" class="uk-input uk-form-blank uk-form-width-medium uk-margin-small-bottom" type="text" disabled>
```